# How to translate parts of source program to library calls without writing a full parser?

Tags: c, parsing, translation

To give an example:

Say I have a very simple library that allows C code to be called from another language L.

In order to use your C code from L you need to change certain constructs in your C code such as changing function types to void, replacing function parameters with a single library type etc. So your C code might change from something like this:

```
double foo(double bar, double baz) {
  return bar + baz;
}
```

to something like this:

```
void foo(LibraryArgs args) {
  double bar = args.get(1);
  double baz = args.get(2);
  setReturn(baz + bar);
}
```

and now your function can be called from L.

I'm trying to write a program that does this transformation automatically when it sees a function marked with some sort of annotation, perhaps something like:

```
@MakeCallableFromL
double foo(double bar, double baz) {
  return bar + baz;
}
```

But I can't seem to find a solution short of writing a near complete parser for C.  Would there be a simpler approach to solving this sort of problem?

Comment: [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) is able to generate bindings to a slew of languages. There might be a way to use SWIG's infrastructure to generate bindings for L.

Comment: perhaps... a wrapper? `void wrap_foo(LibraryArgs args) { setReturn(foo(arg1+arg2); }`. probably it's better to have a look at this package too: https://github.com/eliben/pycparser.

Comment: The most common and simple subset of C is actually not that hard to parse or to write a simple compiler for. However, you might want to take a look at e.g. [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) which has a finished parser you could use, and transform the generated tree into whatever form you want.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr, I like this approach, but since I'm by no means a C expert I have to ask if it's worth the time to worry about the overhead added by making the 1 extra function call (wrapper -> original function) vs having the original function be called directly. Is this overhead something I can ignore?

Comment: @kjh you can ignore. there are too many things else can damage your performance more than adding an extra func call wrapper. at aspect of design, you may get into trouble if you modify all your code in such form. augmented development is always better and guaranteed.

Comment: I whipped up a small test on my machine and the wrapper approach is simple enough and functional. I might end up going with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of parsing wrapper generators out there, chief among these SWIG (which is awesome, and horrible at the same time).

If you can't use SWIG or something like existing parsers:

I'd completely avoid changing the original code -- the C functions must be externally visible, anyway, so it's much much easier to just take the finished shared object, and just extract symbols from it, and generate wrapper code from scratch.

Depending on your framework, there's different options to do that. For `gcc`, `nm` will be the tool of choice, or `objdump -t` or `objdump -T`.

Because you asked for overhead: It will be negligible; a compiler will automatically optimize away most of the unnecessary things that would happen.

Comment: So you're saying that I should essentially compile the original source and use `extern` to create functions that wrap the original calls in L-compatible code, similar to what @HuStmpHrrr Suggests?